# How can i make this line horizontal?

Tags: android

```
for (int x = 0; x < canvas.getHeight(); x += LINE_SPACING) {
canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), paint);
```

this code makes a vertical line. How can i make this horizontal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the concept of x and y reversed:

```
canvas.drawLine(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), 0, paint);
```

Also, it's not clear why you have this in a loop. if you're trying to draw a bunch of horizontal lines, it should be something like:

```
for (int y = 0; y < canvas.getHeight(); y += LINE_SPACING) {
    canvas.drawLine(0, y, canvas.getWidth(), y, paint);
}
```

Comment: i draws just one when i put this in the loop why?

Comment: @user2205733 - Reload my answer; I address that. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int y = 0; y < canvas.getWidth(); y += LINE_SPACING) {
canvas.drawLine(0, 0, canvas.getHeight(), 0, paint);
```